# Wordpress select dropdown list in widget

Tags: plugin-development, widgets

Ok, I'm developing my own widget and I've a HUGE problem.

I don't know how to fetch and eventually save html selects value.

Simple example:

```
/* initialize TITLE */
function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args );
        $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title'] );

(...)

/* update code for TITLE */
    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );

(...)

/* creating TITLE field in widgets admin area */

 <p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e('Title:', 'hybrid'); ?></label>
    <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['title']; ?>" type="text" style="width:100%;" />
 </p>

(...)
```

OK. Now when I type

```
<?php echo $instance['title'] ?>
```

It's going to show my title!

But I have this list:

```
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'example' ); ?> "><?php _e('Map type:', 'example'); ?></label>
<select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'example' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'example' ); ?>">
     <option value="supervalue" selected="selected">Super Value</option>
</select>
```

And

```
<?php echo $instance['example'] ?>
```

Gives NOTHING. I've been looking everywhere including default-widgets.php but I don't understand a word since all default plugins use mostly dynamically generated option lists.

I've used only one item list, but in fact it's longer, I'm not sure how to save the selected element also, since I don't know how to access this element's value.

Any ideas? I spent the whole day on this, getting totally mad slowly.

[edited]

I didn't show you the update function because as I mentioned above I use the same update code for each function.

```
 function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {

    $instance = $old_instance;
    $instance['example'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['example'] );    

    return $instance;

}
```

Comment: i assuming that you are using a class decleration of the widget so post your update function and i think i know whats the problem.

Comment: Dunno if this matters, but shouldn't it be `name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'example' );`? You're using `get_field_id()` above.

Comment: Why isn't the new field inside the update routine? Eg. `$instance['example'] = your_chosen_sanitization_function( $new_instance['example'] );`

Comment: @בניית אתרים done! :)

Comment: It would be alot easier to debug your problem if the complete code could be shown, there's nothing incorrect as far as i can tell with what you've posted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See my comment above...you're using `get_field_id()` on the name-attribute, where it should be `get_field_name()`.

`get_field_id()` returns `'widget-'.$this->id_base.'-'.$this->number.'-'.$field_name`,
whereas
`get_field_name()` returns `'widget-'.$this->id_base.'[' . $this->number . '][' . $field_name.']'`

Comment: What's the difference if I'm using get_field_id everywhere? Also in the first example that is working?

Comment: In the first example you are using `get_field_id()` on the id attribute and `get_field_name()` on the name attribute. In the second example you are using `get_field_id()` on both. Which doesn't work, because now your field value gets registered as `$_POST['widget-base-num-name']` instead of `$_POST['widget-base']['num']['name']`. Obviously, WP maps `$_POST['widget-base']['num']` into the first parameter of `update()`, but it can't do that, so your field value gets lost.

Answer (score 2):

I recently wrote an article about wordpress select boxes on the backend, it might help some of you:

http://wp-dreams.com/wordpress-widget-select-box/